# How to append tags as classes

Tags: wordpress

In a for loop going through all posts how can I append all the tags of the post as part of the class of a div?

```
              <?php
      $page_name = $wp_query->post->post_name;
      query_posts('category_name='. $page_name .'&posts_per_page=-1&orderby=date&order=DESC');
      ?>
          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
              <div class="galleryItem ">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                   <div class="titlePlate">
                      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                  </div><!--END titlePlate-->
              </div><!--END galleryItem-->        

          <?php endwhile; else: ?>

              <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

          <?php endif; ?><?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following codes to print all the tags of the post:

```
<?php
$postid = get_the_ID(); 
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($postid);

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
echo $tag->name . " "; //put a space to seperate every tag.
}
?>
```

These codes will show all the tags of the post, and then you can insert it into the class attribute of the exact Div where you needed.